# Problems using "TextBox".SetFocus firing other events

Tags: vba, userform

I have a user form, `UserForm2` With the following configuration:

- it has four Frames
- All Frames are visible; `Frame1` is not involved in this procedure
- In `Frame2` are three `Textbox`es, two of which are mandatory and one which is optional
- `Frame3` has eight `Textbox`es, all optional
- `Frame4` has seven `Textbox`es, all mandatory

When the first textbox subroutine, `tbxPostNetStore_Exit`, is executed it calls subroutine  `tbxValues(C)`, passing the value `2`. This parameter points to two arrays, `tbx()` and `lbl()`, see below.

Everything worked as it should have, up to the line `MyControl.SetFocus`. At that point it started to re-execute `tbxPostNetStore_Exit`, eventually followed by `Sub tbxPostNetAddress1` and so on.

TextBox `tbxPostNetStore` was Cyan and `tbxPostNetAddress1` was Yellow,  but `SetFocus` was on the last Textbox in `Frame3`!!!

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Each Textbox has Identical coding

I've added additional code to all the TextBox subroutines, see "Call tbxValues(5) as well as the Application.EnableEvents code. The interesting point here is, after adding both the ".EnableEvents" code, control continues to the end of the tbxValues subroutine. On returning to the calling subroutine, control executes the new "Cancel" code and at the end of the calling subroutine, control is handed back to the Application.EnableEvants = True in the tbxValues subroutine. Control once again executes all code to the end of the subroutine, at which point control transfers to the next TextBox, and control is only handed back to the UserForm once the last TextBox in the FRame3 has been reached.

```
'====================================================================================
Private Sub tbxPostNetStore_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call tbxValues(5)
If tbxCancel = True Then  'I added the following code TO ALL THE TextBox
    Cancel = True         'subroutines, and not just those that require
Else                      'an input. Being pedantic, I added the 
    Cancel = False        'Cancel = False also.
End Sub
'====================================================================================
Private Sub tbxPostNetAddress1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call tbxValues(6)
End Sub
'====================================================================================
Private Sub tbxPostNetAddress2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call tbxValues(7)
End Sub 

And so on, up to tbxValues(19)
'====================================================================================
tbxValues() has the following code:
'====================================================================================
Private Sub tbxValues(C)
Dim Asterisk As Integer
tbxCancel = False
Set MyControl = Me.Controls(lbl(C))
Asterisk = InStr(5, MyControl.Caption, "*")
Set MyControl = Me.Controls(tbx(C))
If Asterisk > 0 Then
    If Trim(MyControl.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a value", vbCritical, "Error"
        tbxCancel = True
        MyControl.BackColor = Pink
        MyControl.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
strVar(C) = MyControl.Value
MyControl.BackColor = vbCyan
If Not C = I Then
Set MyControl = Me.Controls(tbx(C + 1))     'Next TextBox
MyControl.BackColor = vbYellow
Application.EnableEvents = False
MyControl.SetFocus  '=========STARTS GOING WRONG HERE
Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
cmbAddNewCustomer.SetFocus
End If
'====================================================================================
End Sub

Private Sub tbxArraySet()
tbx = Array( _
"tbxCustomerID", _
"tbxBOBClientID", _
"tbxCustomerFirstName", _
"tbxCustomerSurName", _
"tbxCompanyName", _
"tbxPostNetStore", _
"tbxPostNetAddress1", _
"tbxPostNetAddress2", _
"tbxPostNetSuburb", _
"tbxPostNetCity", _
"tbxPostNetProvince", _
"tbxPostNetPostCode", _
"tbxPostNetCountry", _
"tbxStreetAddress1", _
"tbxStreetAddress2", _
"tbxStreetPostCode", _
"tbxStreetCountry", _
"tbxCellPhone", _
"tbxLandLine", _
"tbxeMailAddress")
=======================
lbl = Array( _
"lblCustomerID", _
"lblBOBClientID", _
"lblCustomerFirstName", _
"lblCustomerSurName", _
"lblCompanyName", _
"lblPostNetStore", _
"lblPostNetAddress1", _
"lblPostNetAddress2", _
"lblPostNetSuburb", _
"lblPostNetCity", _
"lblPostNetProvince", _
"lblPostNetPostCode", _
"lblPostNetCountry", _
"lblStreetAddress1", _
"lblStreetAddress2", _
"lblStreetPostCode", _
"lblStreetCountry", _
"lblCellPhone", _
"lblLandLine", _
"lbleMailAddress")
```

Comment: If you set `Application.EnableEvents = FALSE` just before your `setfocus` it will not trigger the selection event. Just make sure to set it back to `TRUE` right after selection so the events are enabled again.

Comment: If you do not want re-execution, maybe it is worth suppressing events?

Comment: @Plutian - Thanks for the advice, however, I am sorry to say, it did not stop re-execution of the subroutine. On reaching MyControl.SetFocus, control immediately gets handed back to tbxPostNetStore_Exit. The second time it reaches Application.EnableEvents = False it continues to the end of the sub, but unfortunately, it starts executing the next sub, and in this way, it continues all the way down to the final TextBox, which now has focus.

Comment: @CommonSense - Thank you, but as stated I am a newbie, how do I suppress events? Or is that the same as Application.EnableEvents = False?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `MyControl_GotFocus` somewhere, this will trigger every time the control has focus, whether that is a manual selection or done through VBA. You can suppress this event with `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Which disables all the trigger events until it is switched back on. If your setfocus is the only issue, I suggest resolving like so:

```
Set MyControl = Me.Controls(tbx(C + 1))     'Next TextBox
MyControl.BackColor = vbYellow
Application.EnableEvents = False
MyControl.SetFocus  '=========STARTS GOING WRONG HERE // NOT ANYMORE!
Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
etc.
```

Depending on the rest of the triggers, this might also be needed for `cmbAddNewCustomer.SetFocus`.